# What are the functions of these instructions in C++?

Tags: c++

I am new to programming, especially the C++ language.

I want to know what the work of each of Talimte right and left ..

And in particular the work of the compiler on the line

```
cout << setw (20) << right << setw (20) << left;
```

Also the work of the instruction

```
cin >> setw (20)
```

so I need help.

Comment: This question is in very bad quality. Please reformat it properly if you're expecting to be taken seriously.

Comment: It's not the English being the problem here. Have a look at a few other questions.

Comment: I can't understand very well what is the problem

Comment: Have a look at a few other questions, or check the website guidelines on how to format your question properly.

Comment: If you are looking for general information on these functions you should start at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/): [cout](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) [cin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) and [setw](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::cout`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) is an instance of the [`std::ostream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream) class.  It has numerous [`operator<<()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) implementations for different data types, including a few function types.

[`std::cin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) is an instance of the [`std::istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) class.  It has numerous [`operator>>()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) implementations for different data types, including a few function types.

All of the `operator<<()` and `operator>>()` implementations return a reference to the stream object being called for.  This allows to chaining multiple stream operations into a single statement.

The [`std::setw()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) function returns a I/O manipulator object that can then be passed to `operator<<()` and `operator>>()`. That object remembers the user input value and passes it to the [`width()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/width) method of whichever stream object it is called for.

The [`std::left()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) and [`std::right()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/right) functions are also stream I/O manipulators. They do not take user input as parameters, so they can be passed as-is to `operator<<()` and `operator>>()` (they do not return manipulator objects) to call the stream's [`setf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/setf) method.

So, the line:

```
cout << setw (20) << right << setw (20) << left;
```

Is essentially doing this:

```
... manip = setw(20); // where ... is a compiler-defined type
ostream &temp = cout.operator<<(manip); // calls cout.width(20)
temp.operator<<(&right); // calls temp.setf(std::ios_base::right, std::ios_base::adjustfield)
manip = setw(20);
temp.operator<<(manip); // calls temp.width(20)
temp.operator<<(&left); // calls temp.setf(std::ios_base::left, std::ios_base::adjustfield)
```

Likewise, the line:

```
cin >> setw (20)
```

Is essentially doing this:

```
... manip = setw(20);
cin.operator>>(manip); // calls cin.width(20)
```

Comment: @KasourAbbas: I do not understand what you are asking for

Comment: In my question i give a cod including tow instrucions (right) and (left)... Can i know why we use this instructions

Comment: I have added links to the `std::left` and `std::right` stream manipulators.